# Getting All Elements Using Mouse Down on Text

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build WYSIWYG editor and facing a problem when the user mouses down on the HTML code:

```
<b><i>ABC</i></b>
```

I want to select the **B / Bold** button and the *I / Italic button*, based on tags.

The result I want is that:

when the user mouses down on "ABC", the tags should return `b` and `i`.

Here is my code, but it is only working for one element, and I need a solution for multiple.

```
var ev = arguments[0] || window.event,
origEl = ev.target || ev.srcElement;

alert(origEl.tagName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to be a spoil-sport, but having gone there before, I would strongly recommend against building your own WYSIWIG editor. It's so difficult that even Google gave up*.

Try out http://www.tinymce.com or http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/ - I haven't worked with TinyMCE much, but I can attest that the YUI one is extremely customizable.

* Sort-of, see https://drive.googleblog.com/2010/05/whats-different-about-new-google-docs.html